# Make two elements the same width, show them next to each other as long as it fits, otherwise show them below each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Here is a fiddle that accomplishes the desired result with Javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/ykczmqpg/

```
<style>
    .container {
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .item, .info {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
    }
</style>

<div class=container>
  <div class=item>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
  </div>
  <div class=info>
   This text is supposed to have the same width as the image. Until 2x the width of
   the image does not fit into the container. So here it should be on the right side of the image.
  </div>
</div>

<div class=container>
  <div class=item>
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/50">
  </div>
  <div class=info>
   This text is supposed to have the same width as the image. Until 2x the width of
   the image does not fit into the container. So here it should be below the image.
  </div>
</div>

<script>
 imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
 for (img of imgs)  {
  img.onload = e=> {
    info = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.info');
    w = e.target.width+"px";
    console.log(info);
    info.style.width = w;
  };
 }
</script>
```

Is that possible without Javascript, only with CSS?

I tried with flex, but to no avail so far.

Comment: Does `min-width` work for you?

Comment: `I tried with flex` keep trying ... or try grid

Comment: *as long as it fits* --> what is the constraint here? a text block will always fit with line break and an image can get smaller

Comment: @TemaniAfif The constraint is to have the Fiddle look exactly the same. After removing the JavaScript and changing the CSS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6mrd4u13/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book..</p>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score -1):

Wrap both containers in new  and on that div you can use display:flex and flex-wrap: wrap